# discord bot returns "list index out of range" when trying to dm a member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

basically when I run a normal dm command it dms the user correctly every time but the command worked fine before I added the dm part so I have no idea what line the error is referring to. usually it wouldn't give me an error but it wouldn't do anything at all so I add an Exception to find "list index out of range" a thought i had might be in the for field in embed.fields but I'm not sure...

````
async def tag(ctx, message:int, member: discord.Member, action, *, args):
    try:
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(client.channel)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(message)
        embed = message.embeds[0]
        if member is not None:
            channel1 = member.dm_channel
            if channel1 is None:
                channel1 = await member.create_dm()
            await channel1.send('test')
        if action == "approve":
            embed_dict = embed.to_dict()
            for field in embed_dict["fields"]:
                if field["name"] == "status":
                    field["value"] += f"```python\n{ctx.message.author} tagged this suggestion as **Approved**\nReason:  {args}```"
            embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict)
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
        elif action == "deny":
            embed_dict = embed.to_dict()
            for field in embed_dict["fields"]:
                if field["name"] == "status":
                    field["value"] += f"```python\n{ctx.message.author} tagged this suggestion as **Denied**\nReason:  {args}```"
            embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict)
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
        else:
            ctx.send('please specify approve or deny after the member argument')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
````

there is my code. it takes an embed and adds a "comment" you could call it to the embed.

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your post to include the error message & traceback?

Comment: "so I have no idea what line the error is referring to" how can this even be? In the traceback if you see carefully it will definitely show the line which called the error. So as kelo has pointed out, include your traceback

Comment: it doesnt have traceback without exception

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by `embed = message.embeds[0]` this line as this is the only line when you try to index the list

What this shows?:
The fetched message has no embeds so message.embeds is an empty list `[]` so there is no element at index 0 and thus the error is raised.

Make sure to use the perfect Message ID

Comment: im using the correct message id, it doesnt return an error when i run the command but it gives an error when other people use it... ive checked that my friends are using the correct ids and they are so im not sure why its giving them errors